# How can I make an external USB mouse (mod. Minicute EZMouse) work with Ubuntu?

Tags: usb, mouse

I have just installed Xubuntu 14.04. Everything works fine but the external USB mouse.

[This is the mouse I am trying to use](http://www.minicute.com/products/ezmouse/32.htm). Manufacturer says in its datasheet that it should work on Linux.

When I run `lsusb` the mouse is not present:

```
jose@jose-laptop:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2883 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 025: ID 04f3:0103 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ActiveJet K-2024 Multimedia Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Then when trying to figure out what is happening:

```
jose@jose-laptop:~$ sudo tail -fn 20 /var/log/syslog
Dec  7 19:28:30 jose-laptop kernel: [  908.247190] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 26 using xhci_hcd
Dec  7 19:28:30 jose-laptop kernel: [  908.263405] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/all, error 2
Dec  7 19:28:30 jose-laptop kernel: [  908.375254] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 27 using xhci_hcd
Dec  7 19:28:30 jose-laptop kernel: [  908.391461] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/all, error 2
Dec  7 19:28:30 jose-laptop kernel: [  908.503327] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 28 using xhci_hcd
Dec  7 19:28:30 jose-laptop kernel: [  908.519635] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/all, error 2
Dec  7 19:28:30 jose-laptop kernel: [  908.631390] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 29 using xhci_hcd
Dec  7 19:28:30 jose-laptop kernel: [  908.647608] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/all, error 2
Dec  7 19:28:30 jose-laptop kernel: [  908.647687] hub 3-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
Dec  7 19:28:30 jose-laptop kernel: [  908.759503] usb 3-2: new low-speed USB device number 30 using xhci_hcd
Dec  7 19:28:30 jose-laptop kernel: [  908.781566] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=04f3, idProduct=0103
Dec  7 19:28:30 jose-laptop kernel: [  908.781578] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Dec  7 19:28:30 jose-laptop kernel: [  908.781927] usb 3-2: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
Dec  7 19:28:30 jose-laptop kernel: [  908.781940] usb 3-2: ep 0x82 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
Dec  7 19:28:30 jose-laptop kernel: [  908.786271] input: HID 04f3:0103 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/input/input26
Dec  7 19:28:30 jose-laptop kernel: [  908.786613] hid-generic 0003:04F3:0103.0009: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [HID 04f3:0103] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
Dec  7 19:28:30 jose-laptop kernel: [  908.791297] input: HID 04f3:0103 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.1/input/input27
Dec  7 19:28:30 jose-laptop kernel: [  908.791625] hid-generic 0003:04F3:0103.000A: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [HID 04f3:0103] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input1
Dec  7 19:28:30 jose-laptop mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 30: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2"
Dec  7 19:28:30 jose-laptop mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 30 was not an MTP device
```

Any clue?

UPDATE:

PC is an Asus Laptop running a clean install of Xubuntu 14.04

I have enabled USB Legacy Support in the BIOS and now it works "randomly" when I unplug and plug in again the mouse. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. If I find any other clue I will write about it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days I have finally been able to make the mouse work. All I had to do was enable USB legacy support in my laptop BIOS and disable xHCI support.

Answer (score 1):

Even though minicute says that it is supported on Linux, does not mean the drivers for said device are automatically loaded. Have you tried looking in the software center for additional drivers for the minicute mouse? Some third party proprietary drivers must be downloaded and installed "manually." I find that odd, though, as that mouse looks like it functions like any other mouse...just on it's "side."

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I cannot find any additional drivers. To tell you the truth, I'd be happy to set it up as a generic mouse. I don't care about the custom buttons and stuff. I can't find a way to do that though.

Comment: @novato From the script you posted, it is apparent your comp is able to see it plugged in, but it simply doesn't know what to do with it. Before I research further, I assume you have tried removing all usb devices and only plug in the mouse? Perhaps in a different port (but still all by itself). Also, edit your question and include other details like make/model/specs of your computer so we can have more info to use, as well as if the mouse alone works with nothing else plugged in.

Comment: thank you for following up the question, I have updated it a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

The error `device descriptor read/all, error 2` indicates a unrecoverable problem in the communication with the device on the USB bus. This can have several causes mostly on the electrical level: broken cable, bad voltage, short circuit, bad USB hub…

As a first test you should try to use an other USB port! If you have a hub in between remove it and attach the mouse directly! Make sure all cables and connectors are OK!

Comment: thanks for your answer. Switching to another USB port was my first test. Mouse works fine in Windows. The issue is resolved now, though. Please checkout my answer. http://askubuntu.com/a/558444/355622